# How to access previous row value in pandas lambda function or get the index of each row when doing df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas

See initial question in the end.

I have a dataframe like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Persons':[10,20,30], 'Bill':[110,240,365], 'Guests':[12,25,29],'Visitors':[15,23,27]})
df

Persons     Bill    Guests  Visitors
10          110     12      15
20          240     25      23
30          365     29      27
```

I want a data frame like below

```
Persons     Bill    Guests  Visitors Charge  VisitorsCharge
10          110     12      15       136     175
20          240     25      23       302.5   277.5
30          365     29      27       352.5   327.5
```

Here `Charge` is the interpolated value corresponding to `Guests` with columns `People` & `Bill` as reference.

If we take the first row, we say 10 `People` will rack-up as `Bill` of 110 &  20 `People` will rack-up a `Bill` of 240. So, how much is 12 `Guests` create a `Charge`?

Formula for this is as below

**Row1**

```
import scipy.stats as stats
result = stats.linregress([10,20],[110,240])
slope = result.slope #extract the slope of the interpolation curve
intercept = result.intercept #extract the intercept of the interpolation curve
interpolatedValue  = slope*12 + intercept #interpolate the value
interpolatedValue
```

**Row2**

```
import scipy.stats as stats
result = stats.linregress([20,30],[240,365])
slope = result.slope #extract the slope of the interpolation curve
intercept = result.intercept #extract the intercept of the interpolation curve
interpolatedValue  = slope*25 + intercept #interpolate the value
interpolatedValue
```

**Row3**

```
import scipy.stats as stats
result = stats.linregress([20,30],[240,365])
slope = result.slope #extract the slope of the interpolation curve
intercept = result.intercept #extract the intercept of the interpolation curve
interpolatedValue  = slope*29 + intercept #interpolate the value
interpolatedValue
```

For every row except the last row, we have to use the current & the next row values to get our result.

However, when we reach the last row, we will not have a 'next' row. So, we concatenation current row & previous row values.

We do the same to calculate `VisitorsCharge` as well. But here, we use `Vistors` column value to multiply with "Slope"

A function would solve the issue. However, with lambda function I do not have access to previous & next rows. With df.apply, I am unable to figure out the index of each row as the function is being applied. How do I do it?

##### initial question

I have a dataframe like so

```
A   B   
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

I want a data frame like below

```
A   B   C
1   100 '1-2-100-200'   
2   200 '2-3-200-300'
3   300 '2-3-200-300'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

def compute(i, n=2):
    j = min(i, df.index[len(df)-n])
    idx = df.index[j:j+n]
    result = stats.linregress(df.loc[idx, 'Persons'], df.loc[idx, 'Bill'])
    slope = result.slope
    intercept = result.intercept
    return slope*df.loc[i, 'Guests'] + intercept

df['Charge'] = [compute(i) for i in df.index]
# or
# df['Charge'] = df.index.to_series().apply(compute)
```

output:

```
   Persons  Bill  Guests  Charge
0       10   110      12   136.0
1       20   240      25   302.5
2       30   365      29   352.5
```

Comment: Probably not so efficient with loops.

Comment: @bpfrd sure, but this is the constraint of the question: *"**using `apply`**"*, Given the initial question I doubt the example is really what will be computed. OP has a custom function and they want to be able to access the various rows.

Comment: I thought I could do with `apply()` or a `lambda` function. However, this works too. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `apply` (see the commented line), but likely not more efficient

Answer (score 1):

***NB. solution to initial question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080242/16343464) for an answer to the new question.***

You can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
a = df['A'].astype(str)
b = df['B'].astype(str)
s = a+'-'+a.shift(-1)+'-'+b+'-'+b.shift(-1)
df['C'] = s.ffill()
```

Generalization for an arbitrary number of columns:

```
def cat(s, sep='-'):
    s = s.astype(str)
    return s+sep+s.shift(-1)

df['C'] = df.apply(cat).ffill().agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

output:

```
   A    B            C
0  1  100  1-2-100-200
1  2  200  2-3-200-300
2  3  300  2-3-200-300
```

Comment: I need to actually do linear interpolation of values using the value from either the next row. So, I would prefer using a function with lambda or apply(). I have the logic for the function. I just need to access the values at each row.

Comment: @moys not sure I get you, can you provide an example? I added a function to generalize to any number of columns. To access the other rows, the key is `shift`

Comment: with apply you only get a row at a time. Maybe not so efficient but you can loop over the dataframe manually and apply your interpolation.

Comment: @mozway I added the complete problem. Please have a look.

Comment: can you add data in dict as well? I got some idea!

Comment: @bpfrd I have added the starting df as a dict.

Comment: I added a separate answer for clarity as the problem radically changed

Comment: Thanks for data. Please check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

df['next_persons'] = df.Persons.shift(-1)
df['next_bill'] = df.Bill.shift(-1)

def your_interpolation_func(x, y, z): 
    result = stats.linregress(np.array(x), np.array(y))
    return result.slope*z + result.intercept

df['charge'] = df.apply(lambda row: your_interpolation_func(
    [row.Persons, row.next_persons],
    [row.Bill, row.next_bill],
    row.Guests), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df

    Persons Bill    Guests  next_persons    next_bill   charge
0   10  110 12  20.0    240.0   136.0
1   20  240 25  30.0    365.0   302.5
2   30  365 29  NaN NaN NaN
```

the `NaN` in the last row is because you don't have any next numbers for the last row. You can apply the function to `df.iloc[:-1]` to avoid that.

Comment: I think OP really wanted to have access to the last row

Comment: Since the last row is the same as the previous one, OP can just populate the last row after using shift with the previous row.